# How can I use the dollar sign operator $ to refer to elements of lists *inside* a list in R (or a tibble column if that's different)?

Tags: r, list, syntax, tibble, dollar-sign

I can enter something like

`list(3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3) == 3`

and get back

`TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE`

which is great because it means that I don't have to clumsily use `lapply()` to get R to do what I want. But what if I have a *list of lists*, where the inner lists have named elements. For example, I could have a list of books, where each book is a list consisting of a `$title` and a `$year` in which it was published. Let's say I have a tibble called `books` with just 1 column called `book` that is this list of books. How would I filter for only books published before 2000, or `mutate()` a column containing the titles?

The naive approach I would take to trying to filter by year is:

`filter(books, book$year < 2000)`

because I want it to go through each element of `books$book` and then look at the `$year` element of that, but, since `books$book` is itself a list, R looks for something named `books$book$year` instead of looking for the `$year` element of each element *inside of* `books$book`. How do I get around this without using lapply()?

Just for completeness, here is the (somewhat clumsy looking) way I do it with lapply():

`filter(books, as.logical(lapply(books$book, function(x) x$year < 2000)))`

Comment: It is better to show a small reproducible example.  Perhaps you can try `filter(books, map_lgl(book, ~ any(.x$year < 2000)))` or may be `books %>% mutate(book = map(book, ~ .x %>% filter(year < 2000)))`

Comment: Thank you, `filter(books, map_lgl(books$book, ~ .$year < 2000))` ended up working, didn't know about these `map()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code that you provide above, but you can simplify it to this:

```
filter(books,sapply(book, \(x) x$year<2000))
```

Instead of

```
filter(books, as.logical(lapply(books$book, function(x) x$year < 2000)))
```

The two changes are:

- use `sapply()` instead of `lapply()` which will obviate the need for `as.logical()`
- use the `\(x)` shortcut for `function(x)`

If you really don't want to use lapply/sapply, you can, as @akrun suggests, switch to `map_lgl`, although with a slight simplification:

```
filter(books, map_lgl(book,~x$year<2000))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
filter(books, map_lgl(books$book, ~ .$year < 2000))
```